# Cakephp edit data as a new entry

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.6

I am trying to edit data but here this edit data will be a new entry and old data will we delete.

So I have tried below code to do this

```
public function edit($id = null){
if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put')))
{
    $this->Transaction->create();
    if ($this->Transaction->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Transaction->delete();
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The transaction has been saved.'));
    }

}
```

Here only delete occurred I am not getting new entry data. How can I do this? May anybody help me please?

Answer (score 0):

**IN form edit first assign your id into model primary key. and need to form create() method, and do check your  view source  PUT method are available or not.**

```
 public function edit($id = null){
 if (!$this->Transaction->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
    } 
 if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))){
   $this->Transaction->id=$id;
   if ($this->Transaction->save($this->request->data)) {   
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The transaction has been saved.'));
    }
  }
```

**Another alternate method is updateAll()**
[Cakephp updateAll](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html)

Comment: Where is the difference ?Here I am trying to updated data as a new entry and delete old data.

Comment: $id is associated with your Model primary key

Comment: I already added this exception, My query is , is it possible edited data to make a new entry ?

Comment: yes, it is possible , <form id="Transaction" method="post" action="edit/1">
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT" />

Comment: the above comment PUT value is not available then add new entry

Comment: in edit form hidden input field is generated to override the default HTTP method.

Answer (score 0):

There has many ways to do it. Let see one way

```
public function edit(){

    if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put')))
    {
        $this->Transaction->delete($this->request->params['pass'][0]);  // after post at first delete your entry.

        if ($this->Transaction->save($this->request->data)) {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The transaction has been saved.'));
        }

    }else {
        //to get this id data.
        $id = $this->request->params['pass'][0];
        $options = array('conditions' => array('Transaction.' . $this->Transaction->primaryKey => $id));
        $this->request->data = $this->Transaction->find('first', $options);
    }
```

I thik it can help you.